# What does it mean Read IOMeter Bootup?

Tags: ssd

I am hoping I have posted a question to a right area in stack exchange.
Anyways, I am buying a SSD and I came across in benchmark results, some labels that read:

"`Read IOMeter Bootup`" and "`Read IOMeter IOMix`"

I am wondering what does it mean? And how much does that influence in reading small size files, as this is mostly the area I am going to be using my SSD?

For example on pages:

http://www.ssdreview.com/review/compare/samsung-serie-840-evo-250gb-25-inch-ext0ab0q/
http://www.ssdreview.com/review/compare/kingston-hyperx-3k-240gb-25-inch-503abbf0/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iometer

Comment: :) you could have gave me a link http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Read+IOMeter+IOMix :) I have seen that page, but there is nothing that explains bootup and io mix. What does that mean

Answer (score 0):

IOMeter is a benchmarking program. Try taking a look at their user manual as they can probably describe their features of Bootup and IOMix better than I can.

http://www.iometer.org/doc/documents.html